# How do I use one computer as the firewall of another computer?

Tags: windows-xp, firewall, adsl, adsl-router

I recently obtained a Netgear router together with an ADSL line. I have two PCs PC1 and PC2.

I want PC1 to have complete control over PC2, e.g. serve as a firewall for PC2. I should also be able to block PC2 from accessing certain websites. PC1 runs Windows XP. PC2 also Windows XP.

Is there a way I can accomplish this? If so, how?

Comment: As an alternative, to block websites: make PC2 use a filtering DNS such as http://www.opendns.com You could also set up that DNS in the router, and then set up PC1 to *not* use OpenDNS. (Of course, smart people can get around it. Smarter people could block port 53 to ensure the DNS from the router is used.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Netgear Router itself is a much better firewall than your PC.

Also, depending on the model, it might also do Access Policy. Logon to it according to the instructions you received with it, and search for such options.

Otherwise, if you control PC2, just install some parental control software on it, for example [K9 Web Protection](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/).

Comment: Why down-vote? Is the time I spent on this problem just worthless?

Comment: Odd indeed. I know you don't need the reputation, nor will forget that downvote if I upvote, but nevertheless: +1 for coming up with an answer despite the few details in the question :-)

Comment: @Arjan: Many thanks for your quick point relief. I know that not every SU visitor fully understands the answers (or questions), but somehow a down-vote is still downright insulting...